# Document Library - filtering or permissions, how to?

Tags: document-library, permissions

First of all, i'm learning SP, so it might be a silly question.

I got superusers and users. Users must be allowed to see the content of the library and only the items, they have uploaded. Superusers must be allowed to see everything in the same library. So how do i do this?

I did use this one - it kinda works:

Created by: [Me].

OR

Modified by: [Me].

But i dont know what the 3rd parameter supposed to be, as this filtering only shows uploaded content by the user. And i need a 3-4 people, who can see what everyone have uploaded.

Another solution could be a document library, where the users got the permission to upload files, but not download, while supersusers can download and upload. The issue here is, when i assign custom permission level, with add and view, it doesnt work. I got the visitors group and custom permission level with same users. When i remove the from the visitors group, they cant visit the site. Its just a guess, but doesn't visitors and my custom permission get in conflict somehow?

Thanks alot.:)

Answer (score 2):

There are different aspects here:

1. Only security does properly restrict access to content. Only using
   Views, simply means hiding items from view, but those more
   experience users could still use Default view, or other ways to gain
   access to content. Check you scenarios and use proper model. You
   could also rely on Target audience (via List Settings) to hide
   specific List Item/Document for an item, but this doesn't change
   security, only showing content to target people or groups.
2. What super-users really mean to you? Using Unique Security on a sub-site creates automatically 3 groups - Owners (??super-users?), Contributors, Visitors, which are given permissions. Owners get automatically overall control on that particular Sub-Site. There is also Site Collection Administrator - which get full control across all site and sub-sites.
3. Breaking security inheritance could be used to adapt to cases when a Library or even a Document/list item requires special security. It should carefully used as it can quickly lead to a complete loss of control. Only site collection administrator will be able to reset back to default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Lists have an option in Advanced List Settings to only allow users to see their own items but libraries do not support this.  Site Collection Administrators can still see all items in a list even with this setting applied.

You could take advantage of this concept to meet your requirement by using a list with a link to a document.  The documents themselves would have to live in separate libraries but you could set appropriate permissions on the libraries (or the users could upload them to MySites) to achieve the security level you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

Im still looking for a satisfying solution. I try to explain, what i got right now and i hope you can help me.

All i need is:

1)Group A must be able to upload, but not download from a specific document libary.

2)Group B must be able to download but not upload, from the same document libary.

4)Group A and B must not be able to edit the site content.

5)Im using SP2013.

6)I already got my users/groups ready(AD).

I tryed to accomplish this, by modifying the view of the document libary, but im not sure if this is the best method.

I really need you help, thanks alot. What can i do?